# How to find out the pitch of a melody in Ableton live 10?

Tags: melody, ableton-live, pitch

I have a sample that plays 4 chords. I have no idea what their key/pitch is. I've tried using the tuner audio effect but it doesn't say anything at all. Does anyone know an alternate way to find the pitch of a sample?

Comment: Do you own *any* other musical instrument?

Comment: I have a launchpad pro. Does that count?

Comment: Yes, kind of… but not really in this context, because it doesn't use quantifiable notes. The very simplest way to find out what note something is playing is to find the same note on any instrument you can name the notes of [whether you do this by "talent" or by hitting notes at random until you find one that matches is really just a matter of expediency;)

Comment: Isn't there some sort of tool or audio effect that can do what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Melodyne can recognise multiple pitches in chords etc, but at €150 I'm sure it would be cheaper & simpler to find some old keyboard & just play at "find the note" like musicians have been doing for centuries.

Comment: Have you tried converting harmony to MIDI?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app called TE Tuner, available in the Apple and Google play store. This app has a function called Analysis which displays pitch, and another function called Sound - which will display the key of whatever ‘sound’ it hears. HTH Catz

Comment: Can that identify chords? It doesn't look like it can.

Comment: I have used it for chord practice, using the Sound selection. it does not recognize every chord.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the 'audio to midi' conversion of a clip. See [Chapter 12.2 of Ableton Live manual](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/converting-audio-to-midi/)